# How can I remove the target directory selection in Qt installer?

Tags: linux, qt, installation, qt-installer

I am trying to make an installer on Linux with Qt Installer Framework and I'd like to set a fixed target dir and remove that page from the installer. I've managed to do this with a script and using setDefaultPageVisible. This works but I have to press the next button twice in order to get past it.

Is this a known issue or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of others, I found a solution. It seems that you need to remove the Introduction page as well as TargetDirectory as there appears to be a duplicate Introduction page otherwise.

```
function Component()
{
    installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.Introduction, false);
    installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.TargetDirectory, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the line edit with currentPage.TargetDirectoryLineEdit.enabled = false;